# WCF 4.0 REST IIS Hosted Long Running Operation No Response after 1 hr

Tags: wcf, wcf-rest, wcf-configuration

I have an IIS Hosted WCF REST 4.0 service.  When I execute a rest operation that takes over an hour to run it never returns a response to the client. Instead I receive the following exception after 4 hours:

*"The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 03:59:59.9979998. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout"*

I have set the WebHttpBinding SendTimeout and ReceiveTimeout on both the client and the server to 4 hours. I have also set the asp.net httpRuntime executionTimeout="7200".

I know for a fact the service operation completes most of the time in just over 1 hour (app logging). If it happens to complete faster than an hour the response is returned perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using request-reply way to call the service and your client waits for 1 hour to get the reply, why not use callback operation so that the service can send reply to client when it's done and the client won't need to wait?